How can I convert the decimal values in a BigDecimal to Zero always in java
Example.
Input:  4066508.33
output : 4066508.00

Tried
DecimalFormat decimalFormat= new DecimalFormat("#.00");
decimalFormat.format(num))

also
String.format("%.2f", num));

Both returned 4066508.33 only. Please suggest a solution

You can not get from 4066508.33 to 4066508.00 by rounding. A formatter producing your intended output for this input would be lying.

If you are asking about "How to stringify and flooring a number", then whatever the type of number is double, float, or BigDecimal, it can be:
String.format("%.0f.00", decimal)

If you're asking about just flooring a BigDecimal, it could be:
// Convert and truncate to BigInteger
decimal.toBigInteger()
// Or want to keep the scale
decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)


Just do it as follows.
BigDecimal[]  data = {
        new BigDecimal("29292.833"),
        new BigDecimal("29292.133"),
        new BigDecimal("29292")
};

for (BigDecimal d : data) {
    System.out.printf("%d.00%n",d.toBigInteger());
}

prints
29292.00
29292.00
29292.00

